# Code changes not reflected in .apk [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-tools

Since morning my code changes are not being reflected in .apk.
I did not updated anything. I saw some post here pointing out to sdk-tools.
But I haven't touched sdk-tools. What can be the possible reason?

Comment: Did you save after changing the code? 1.Save the code 2.generate signed apk and try running it now if you are using an android device to check.

Comment: Well i am trying to debug w=using a mini USB connected through my PC. Does this effect??

Comment: @Nbajam2015 no that should work fine. Debugging like that also generates apk's

Answer (score 6):

Try clean (Build->Clean Project) and rebuild (Build->Rebuild Project) your solution.

Comment: It's really unbelievable! Android Studio is probably one of the worst projects Google has ever released... I wonder if some involved people there got fired..

Comment: Ugh having the same issue. It will not update the apk file

Answer (score 1):

Gradle tends to cache some parts of the .apk to speed-up the building process. In most cases, doing a clean (*Build -> Clean Project*) will solve such issues :-)

You can also clean all the already-created elements by deleting the */build* subdirectory of your project and rebuilding.

Comment: tried everything, nothing works :(

Comment: I have already tried : 1. reinstalling Android studio 2. using a different PC 3. using multiple devices . Nothing works for me. My code does not update and shows the old feature...

Comment: Ok then, could you please summarise what code it is and what it does? (in the question)

Comment: i'm having the same issue... also tried everything. very strange.

Comment: There may be a new reason now - if you are using the beta/canary channel for Android Studio, there is now an option called Instant Run, which (simply speaking) hotswaps parts of the code at runtime. Go to settings, search for Instant Run and turn it off, as it is extremely buggy right now and may cause this problem.